# Os fingerprinting with MAC address

Tags: operating-system, mac-address, fingerprinting

Does anyone know how you can perform OS fingerprinting using MAC address? What about os fingerprinting with IP address?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just something to note: both MAC and IP addresses can be spoofed rather easily.  Not too familiar with how to do this, nor what type of implementation you're trying to do (not really specified in the tags).

Comment: Uh, I'm not actually trying to do this practically. I am asked to provide an explanation on how it can be acheived, i.e. how can you use the MAC address structure to find out information about a user's OS?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: being that this isn't about a specific code implementation of fingerprinting, @KenWhite is correct, in that it probably shouldn't be here in that case.  You might be able to look through SuperUser and stumble across some more information specific to this.

Comment: Ok, then, sorry :s Should I close the subject/mark as resolved...?

Answer (score 0):

for MAC address i dont know....but for ip address u can use xprobe2..but u need to be connected to the network and know their internal IP... in terminal type xprobe2 192.168.xx.xx

replace xx with the ip address.